# iOS - Error with constraints in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints

I would like to place the button through the constraints is the same for all devices. As you can see in the first picture (iPhone 6) the button is set properly, while the iPad Pro button is too low. How can I fix?

[Open pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHYr4.jpg)

Comment: what do you expect? do you want the view and the button to always be centered vertically?

Comment: yes......!!!!!!

Comment: I want to put the button below the two textfield in each device